# What is Samuel's motivation in the bad ending of Dishonored?

Tags: dishonored

In the Evil (bad) ending of Dishonored, Samuel fires a flare to alert the guards, saying that Corvo is not so different to the antagonists. Why did he do that, knowing Corvo is the only hope to find and save Emily?

Comment: Do you mean the "evil" ending?

Comment: Yes the one happens if you kill too many people

Comment: Presumably someone so evil wouldn't be the right person to save Emily.

Comment: @Close Voters - This isn't a game design/developer question, it's a plot question, one of our [*primary on-topic areas of expertise*](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Joshua Shane Liberman  as i mentioned the only hope is corvo presuming we already have killed Daud , so there is no one else to save her.

Comment: @Robotnik I would argue that plot questions aren't one of our primary areas of expertise; rather, they're one of the most contentious areas we have.  As evidenced by all the "Game Dev!", "No, plot!" arguments we get into.

Comment: So why the plot explanation part of the movies sector always gets answer? Gamers are not interested in the plot , thats why . But i Don't play a game only because of the gameplay , story matters to me too . as half-life series got a strong story rather than a strong gameplay . anyway as i see any one does not care about the plot can skip these kind of question . but plot is almost as important as the other elements.

Answer (score 5):

In my humble opinion it's simply this: to get the "High Chaos" ending you have to have pretty much killed everything in your path, and this has been eating away at Samuel (whose comments become increasingly sour as you progress through the missions even before the end).

By the time Samuel has delivered Corvo to Kingsparrow Island, the long boat journey has forced him to ask himself: will the young empress be any better off in the hands of this mass murderer? And, having decided that things could only be worse with Corvo hovering over the throne, Samuel tries to throw him to the wolves.